# scroll to a particular row after creating jquery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery DataTables

```
var oTable = $('#table1').dataTable({
    'sScrollY': '400px',
    'iDisplayLength':   20,
    'bAutowidth': false,
    'bScrollInfinite': true,
    'bScrollCollapse': true,
    'aaData': arr,
    'aoColumns': [
                {'sTitle': 'Name', 'mDataProp': 'name'},
                {'sTitle': 'Company', 'mDataProp': 'company'},
                {'sTitle': 'Salary', 'mDataProp': 'salary'}
                  ]
});

$('.dataTables_scrollBody').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.dataTables_scrollBody').offset().top    

}, 500);
```

This creates the dataTable but does not do any scroll. I want to scroll to a particular table after dataTable is created. How can that be achieved.

Comment: Adding a unique ID to each row and then use it as the selector of your scrollTop?

Comment: Running $('.dataTables_scrollBody').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.dataTables_scrollBody').offset().top    

}, 500);  from the console scrolls to the top. However, placing it in the code after initialization does not scroll the table.

Comment: Try putting the scroll code in fnInitComplete callback.